# cannot use orderBy or groupBy function in Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I create a DataFrame which is showed as below:

```
val file = sc.textFile(FileName)
case class CreateDF(project:String, title:String, requests_num:Int, return_size:Int)
val df = file.map(line=>line.split(" ")).map(line=> CreateDF(line(0),line(1),line(2).toInt,line(3).toInt)).toDF()


+-------+--------------------+------------+-----------+
|project|               title|requests_num|return_size|
+-------+--------------------+------------+-----------+
|     aa|%CE%92%CE%84_%CE%...|           1|       4854|
|     aa|%CE%98%CE%B5%CF%8...|           1|       4917|
|     aa|%CE%9C%CF%89%CE%A...|           1|       4832|
|     aa|%CE%A0%CE%B9%CE%B...|           1|       4828|
|     aa|%CE%A3%CE%A4%CE%8...|           1|       4819|
|     aa|%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B...|           1|       4750|
|     aa|             271_a.C|           1|       4675|
|     aa|Battaglia_di_Qade...|           1|       4765|
|     aa|    Category:User_th|           1|       4770|
|     aa|  Chiron_Elias_Krase|           1|       4694|
|     aa|County_Laois/en/Q...|           1|       4752|
|     aa|    Dassault_rafaele|           2|       9372|
|     aa|Dyskusja_wikiproj...|           1|       4824|
|     aa|              E.Desv|           1|       4662|
|     aa|Enclos-apier/fr/E...|           1|       4772|
|     aa|File:Wiktionary-l...|           1|      10752|
|     aa|Henri_de_Sourdis/...|           1|       4748|
|     aa|Incentive_Softwar...|           1|       4777|
|     aa|Indonesian_Wikipedia|           1|       4679|
|     aa|           Main_Page|           5|     266946|
+-------+--------------------+------------+-----------+
```

my target is to get the records which have largest return_size,
so I want to use orderBy function,df.orderBy("return_size"), and I also try to use df.groupBy("return_size").max().
but it doesn't work.......

An error occurs:

```
    scala> df.orderBy("return_size").show
2018-04-08 15:47:05 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 10)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2371877485"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
    at $line19.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
    at $line19.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:30)
    at org.spark_project.guava.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:670)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1427)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1424)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-04-08 15:47:05 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 10, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2371877485"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
    at $line19.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
    at $line19.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:30)
    at org.spark_project.guava.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:670)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1427)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1424)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2018-04-08 15:47:05 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
2018-04-08 15:47:05 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 2.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 12, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
2018-04-08 15:47:05 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 11, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 10, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2371877485"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
    at $anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
    at $anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:30)
    at org.spark_project.guava.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:670)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1427)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1424)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2124)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1029)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1011)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1.apply(RDD.scala:1433)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.takeOrdered(RDD.scala:1420)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TakeOrderedAndProjectExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3253)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3252)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:723)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:682)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:691)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2371877485"
  at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
  at $anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
  at $anonfun$2.apply(<console>:27)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
  at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:30)
  at org.spark_project.guava.collect.Ordering.leastOf(Ordering.java:670)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Utils$.takeOrdered(Utils.scala:37)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1427)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$takeOrdered$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1424)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

could anyone tell me how to solve this problems, or any other solution for getting the max value of column return_size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read the file as

```
val file = sc.textFile("/home/user1/project2/pagecounts-20160101-000000")
```

it is read as *string*. And you have `request_num` and `return_size` as *Int* but *2371877485* is a very large number so the error occured.

> > java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2371877485"

the solution is to change your case class to

```
case class CreateDF(project:String, title:String, requests_num:BigInt, return_size:BigInt)
```

and then use it like

```
val df = file.map(line=>line.split(" ")).map(line=> CreateDF(line(0),line(1),line(2).asInstanceOF[BigInt],line(3).asInstanceOF[BigInt])).toDF()
```

You can find more information [scala api doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Int$.html) which states

> > `final val MaxValue: Int(2147483647)
> >     The largest value representable as an Int.`

Comment: many thanks, it help a lot, I forget to check the type of data

Answer (score 1):

your code converts values to Integers but you also have values like (2371877485) that don't fit in an integer - convert to Long instead

```
val df = file.map(line=>line.split(" ")).map(line=> CreateDF(line(0),line(1),line(2).toInt,line(3).toLong)).toDF()
```

Comment: many thanks, it help a lot, I forget to check the type of data